# Android RealtiveLayout can't handle overlapping right

Tags: android, android-animation, android-relativelayout, android-framelayout

I'm using a layout similiar to this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/list_item_background"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="35sp"
        android:text="18:15" />

   <!-- some more views on the right side-->

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutActive"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/textView1">

       <!-- contains several other views, a RelativeLayout and a FrameLayout-->
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I now want to perform two animations on the layout:

1. fade out `relativeLayoutActive` (AlphaAnimation) and translate all views of the right side to the left
2. fade in `relativeLayoutActive` and translate all views back to the left side

here is my code I'm using for the animations:

```
public void activate(boolean isActive){
    if(!this.active && isActive && checkIfActivatable()){   // start animation 2
        if(animating)
            return;
        animating = true;
        animatingActive = isActive;
        rootView.addView(relativeLayoutActive);
        translate(rootView, clock, true);
        fade(relativeLayoutActive, true, 1, 0, null, this, false);
                    //...
    }else if(this.active && !isActive){  // start Animation 1
        if(animating)
            return;
        animating  = true;
        animatingActive = isActive;
        translate(rootView, clock, false);
        fade(relativeLayoutActive, false, 1, 0, null, this, false); 
                    //...
        view.removeView(relativeLayoutActive);
    }
}

private void translate(View targetParent, View target, boolean right){
        Animation a = new TranslateAnimation(0.0f,
                (right?1:-1)*(targetParent.getWidth() - target.getWidth() - view.getPaddingLeft() -
                view.getPaddingRight()), 0.0f, 0.0f);
        a.setDuration(500);
        a.setInterpolator(AnimationUtils.loadInterpolator(getContext(),
                        android.R.anim.decelerate_interpolator));
        a.setFillAfter(true);
            target.startAnimation(a);
    }

    private void fade(View target, boolean in, float inValue, float outValue, AnimationSet as, AnimationListener listener, boolean useAs){
        Animation a = new AlphaAnimation(in?outValue:inValue, in?inValue:outValue);
        a.setDuration(500);
        a.setFillAfter(true);
        if(listener!=null){
            a.setAnimationListener(listener);
        }
        if(!useAs)
            target.startAnimation(a);
        else{
            as.addAnimation(a);
            target.startAnimation(as);
        }
    }
```

When the animations end the "animation-change" is made permanent by calling view.clearAnimations() and setting the right layoutParams.

Animation 1 works perfectly, but 2 doesn't. Everything works like it should except for the fade in of `relativeLayoutActive`. Not till the animation is ended `relativeLayoutActive` becomes visible at all i.e. `relativeLayoutActive` is unvisible during the animation.

I think this happens because `RelativeLayout` can't handle overlapping and since `relativeLayoutActive` is covered by over views at the begin of 2. it gets not visible till the animation ends

How can I solve this?

regards

Comment: Can you share the complete layout file?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your problem stems from z-ordering of views/viewgroups.

> I think this happens because RelativeLayout can't handle overlapping
>   and since relativeLayoutActive is covered by over views at the begin
>   of 2. it gets not visible till the animation ends

I am not sure what you mean by `overlapping`. But you can call:

```
relativeLayoutActive.bringToFront();
```

to change/fix the z-ordering. You will need to call this after:

```
rootView.addView(relativeLayoutActive);
```

Here is what `View#bringToFront()` does:

> **public void  bringToFront ()**
>
> Change the view's z order in the tree, so it's on top of other sibling
>   views. This ordering change may affect layout, if the parent container
>   uses an order-dependent layout scheme (e.g., LinearLayout). Prior to
>   KITKAT this method should be followed by calls to requestLayout() and
>   invalidate() on the view's parent to force the parent to redraw with
>   the new child ordering.

Additionally, I would recommend using android's newer animation framework if you are working with API 11 and above. It is highly optimized and provides much better user experience. [Link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/package-summary.html)